# Overwrite JW Player shortcuts

Tags: javascript, html, jwplayer

I want to navigate through the JW player controlbar using my own listener instead of the already provied shortcuts. This way whenever I press right key it would select the item of a list. I already got the selection part, but when I press right it also activates the shortcut of going 10s forward.
How can I disable the pre recorded shortcuts?